# Including a C tool in a Xcode4 project

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4, osx-snow-leopard

I have a project which builds two targets, the main app and a tool.

How can I correctly include the tool in the app bundle? I have already navigated to target dependencies and added the tool; however when adding the built executable to the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase, I get a path to the builded product like:

```
.../.../awieuhfaowasldijfsalkdj/Build/Debug/tool
```

Is there any way to add the tool to the bundle dynamically, I mean without hardcoding such path? Ideally, I'd like to add the tool in a special folder (say "Tools") inside the "Resources" bundle folder, but I don't even know if that's possible.

Apart from this, is there something else I need to do in order to complete the process of adding it as a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to avoid the weird path is to specify that the build location should be the one specified by the targets (by default `build/Debug` or `build/Release` under the project folder):

- Open the Xcode preferences
- Click on the **Locations** tab
- Under **Build Location**, select **Place build products in locations specified by targets**

Comment: That certainly make it easy. I was worried not only with the path tidiness, but also with the functionality. Who knows, maybe the path is temporary and then the project gets broken. The Xcode 3 way still the best, thanks Laurent!